# Java generic arithmetic

Tags: java, generics, primitive

I'm trying to create some Java classes, that should work with either float or double numbers (for simulation purposes I am required to support both). The classes need to do some basic arithmetic and also require use of trigonometric functions (sin, cos, atan2).

I tried to do a generic approach. As Java does not allow primitive types in generics and `MyClass<T extends Number>` does indeed allow Double and Float, but makes basic arithmetic impossible, I build a wrapper class around Double and Float. But this approach fails, as soon as I need to instantiate a value in one of the generic classes.

Is there any clean way to support both float and double, without duplicating all the code for each type?

Comment: If you write the the method for double you can use it for float as well..

Comment: Do you need to work with wrapper classes or with primitives?

Comment: @Thihara Yes, but the method will then return a double, independent of the type of its parameters. I need to stay with the given precision.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov: I do not need to use the Number wrapper classes, but for using collections it would be helpful, if some kind of wrapper class could be used in the solution. I mainly need to do arithmetic. With primitives only I would have to write all the methods once per type, if possible I want to avoid that.

Comment: If you use Number then you will have to do the checks to ensure its actualls Doubles and Floats that's passed...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From experience, if you're doing hardcore numerical work in Java, it's better to stick to primitive types. This means that generics are a no-go for this type of work (but of course are perfectly fine for many other uses).

> Is there any clean way to support both float and double, without duplicating all the code for each type?

You could implement the lower-precision method in terms of the higher-precision one:

```
public static double calc(double x, double y) {
   // do the calculation and return double
}

public static float calc(float x, float y) {
   return (float)calc((double)x, (double)y);
}
```

Comment: thanks, I decided to use something like that. Not as generic as I hoped, but it doesn't look like there is a way for generics and arithmetic to work together well in Java

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
class MyClass<T extends Number> {
    T add(T t1, T t2) {
        if (t1 instanceof Double) {
            return (T) Double.valueOf((t1.doubleValue() + t2.doubleValue()));
        } else if (t1 instanceof Float) {
            return (T) Float.valueOf(((t1.floatValue() + t2.floatValue())));
        } else if (t1 instanceof Integer) {
            return (T) Integer.valueOf(((t1.intValue() + t2.intValue())));
        }
        // you can add all types or throw an exception
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass<Double> mc = new MyClass<Double>();
        mc.add(1.0, 1.1);
    }
}
```